# Building QuantLib on Amazon Linux

Tags: compiling, rpm, libraries, aws, amazon-linux

I am trying to get [QuantLib](https://www.quantlib.org/) version 1.13 running on Amazon Linux.

I found some `.rpm` files at https://pkgs.org/download/QuantLib, although there is an up to date `.rpm` for Fedora, there isn't one for CentOS (the CentOS files seem to be compatible with Amazon Linux).

I was able to successfully build the library from source, however when I do so it creates a 1.2GB `libQuantLib.a` file and a 421MB `libQuantLib.so.0.0.0` file.

The `.rpm` files at https://pkgs.org/download/QuantLib are all ~25MB.

Ultimately I am trying to pack QuantLib well enough that I can run it in an AWS Lambda environment. This would require the compressed binaries to be ~50MB and be compatible with the Amazon Linux AMI for Lambda.

**My question**:

- Why is there such a discrepancy between the size of the `.rpm` file and the `libQuantLib.a` / `libQuantLib.so.0.0.0` files that result when I build from source? Is the `.rpm` file not a full version of the library? Does the result of my build contain a lot of fluff?
- Is it possible to build from source and achieve the ~25MB size or is this effort fruitless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your hand-built libraries are built with debugging information, that's why they are so big. You can try `strip libQuantLib.so.0.0.0` and see how much smaller it will get.

You can try to rebuild the official RPM for *Amazon Linux 2* like this:

1. Download the source RPM (`QuantLib-1.4-7.el7.src.rpm`)
2. Install `rpm-build` package (or `rpmbuild`? not quite sure what's the name on *AL2*)
3. Run `rpmbuild --rebuild QuantLib-1.4-7.el7.src.rpm` and if everything goes right you should have the `QuantLib-...x86_64.rpm` built for *Amazon Linux 2* after a while.

There *may* be some dependency issues. If you're not familiar with building RPMs feel free to follow up here or open another question.

However this should get you started. Good luck with it :)

**Update - building without `QuantLib-doc` package.**

As per the comment below building the `QuantLib-doc` requires a lot of extra dependencies. To rebuild it without *doc* do the following:

1. Download source RPM, e.g. to `/tmp`
2. In an empty directory run `rpm2cpio /tmp/QuantLib-...src.rpm`
3. Edit `QuantLib.spec` and comment out `%package doc`, `%description doc` and `%files doc` sections
4. Build the RPM with `rpmbuild -ba QuantLib.spec`

That should remove the need to install the many dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I was able to run the rebuild command after installing the dependencies. Two of the dependencies were large Latex packages. I can't imagine they are required to run the library, is it possible they are just required to build it?

Comment: Most likely LaTeX is needed for `QuantLib-doc` package. If you want to build the RPM without the -doc package you'll have to modify the *spec* file. I'll edit the answer above with the instructions.

Comment: quick question, does a library that requires `boost` to compile require `boost` to run?

Comment: @bphi re `boost` - it depends how it is linked, if statically or dynamically. More often than not *dynamic* linking is used which in turn means it will be required in runtime, yes.