# Rebuild from src.rpm using new version

Tags: compiling, rpm, libraries, rpmbuild, amazon-linux

This is a follow up to my previous question regarding [Building QuantLib on Amazon Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470800/building-quantlib-on-amazon-linux).

I followed the instructions in the answer posted by MLu:

1. Download the source RPM (QuantLib-1.4-7.el7.src.rpm)
2. Install `rpmbuild`
3. Run `rpmbuild --rebuild QuantLib-1.4-7.el7.src.rpm`

However the result was a series of `QuantLib-(devel/doc/test)-1.4-7.el7.rpm` `rpms`.

I had hoped the result would be `QuantLib-1.13.el7.src.rpm`.

Is it possible to modify the rebuild process to use the newest release of the library `1.13`? The source code is available here https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpmbuild --rebuild QuantLib-1.4-7.el7.src.rpm` will "just" extract the source package to `~/rpmbuild/{SPEC,SOURCES}/` and run `rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPEC/QuantLib`. Nothing else.

You want to rebase to new version, which can be easy or tricky. Hard to say in advance.

The easy version is that you

1. `rpm -Uvh QuantLib-1.4-7.el7.src.rpm`
2. `cd ~/rpmbuild/SOURCE`
3. create tar.gz from the upstream git repository and put it to this directory. optionaly you can dele the old version which is in this directory.
4. edit ~/rpmbuild/SPEC/QuantLib.spec and change `Version`, `Release`, `Source0` and edit `%changelog`.
5. run `rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPEC/QuantLib.spec`

Sometimes this work. Usually for simple projects or for well maintained projects.

Sometimes the last step fails with ... nearly anything. There is zilion options to fail. To fix that you should really know how packaging RPM works. The good start is to read https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/

Note that QuantLib maintain spec file in their github repository. This may help you.

And once you build the package, you can make world better and build it in https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org where others can easily find it and use it.